# Docker volumes mount windows share folder without IP address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to mount a volume on a docker container, which point to a windows share. The share is accessible with path `//mypath/c` and its ip is `10.10.10.6`

This is working :

```
volumes:
  mysharefolder:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=username,password=pwd,rw,domain=mydomain
      device: "\\\\10.10.10.6\\c$$"
```

And if I just replace the ip adresse by its corresponding dns name as following
`device: "//mypath/c"`, I get an error when mounting volume to a container :

`ERROR: for testwritefile  Cannot start service myimage: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_mysharefolder/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount //mypath/c:/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_mysharefolder/_data: invalid argument`

I also can cd from a linux environnement `cd //mypath/c`.

I have tried many things but seems like I have to put the IP address which is not acceptable for me (has IP address is changing frequently).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the device to:

```
device: "//10.10.10.6/c$$"
```

If just changing to / don't work try below.

My configuration worked with these options:

```
o: username=${USER},password=${CIFS_PASS},file_mode=0774,dir_mode=0774
```